# GStreamer macOS Big Sur Camera Input

Tags: macos, gstreamer, macos-big-sur, gstreamer-1.0

I'm trying to build a GStreamer pipeline that uses the built in webcam on my MacBook and also another camera plugged in via USB. It's my understanding that at some point on MacOS the cameras used to show up under /dev and I would be able to run something like:

gst-launch-1.0 autovideosrc device=/dev/video0 ! autovideosink

The above command no longer works since it cannot find video0. In fact, there are no video devices that show up under /dev and it looks like you are supposed to use the Apple SDK to access the hardware from now on.

Is there a new plugin or documentation somewhere on how get video input working on macOS Big Sur?

Answer (score 2):

Florian Zwoch's comment lead to reconsider how I installed GStreamer. Initially I used homebrew to install it. I then installed it by following the instructions on the GStreamer website: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-mac-osx.html?gi-language=c

I had to add /Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/bin to my PATH to access the commands but after that I was able to get video from my webcam using either of the following prototypes:

gst-launch-1.0 autovideosrc device=/dev/video0 ! autovideosink

gst-launch-1.0 avfvideosrc ! osxvideosink

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have `avfvideosrc`, see https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-bad/blob/master/sys/applemedia/avfvideosrc.m.

Comment: No I don't. When I run 'gst-inspect-1.0 | grep -i video | grep -I source' all I get are: videotestsrc:  videotestsrc: Video test source
autodetect:  autovideosrc: Auto video source
opengl:  gltestsrc: Video test source

Comment: Depending on how you installed it check upon options or build it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you may check the video device by `gst-device-monitor-1.0` first

then input

```
gst-launch-1.0 avfvideosrc device-index=1 ! autovideosink
```